# How To select record If foreign key is not exist In Foreign key table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need To Select Record from primary key table if the foreign key record in Foreign key table  Is not exist

```
SELECT Id FROM tbl1 T,tbl2 U  WHERE T.Id <> U.Id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS()`

```
SELECT Id
FROM Tbl1 T
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM Tbl2 U
                  WHERE U.Id = T.Id
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a left join, and then looking for the nulls that indicate the missing values.

SELEC T.Id FROM tbl1 T Left join tbl2 U on T.Id = U.Id Where u.id is null